# Queries on Javascript Libraries

Tags: jquery, web-applications, javascript

I have been trying to look at how javascript libraries work to have a better idea in general, but I don't really understand them. I have a little programming knowledge in java and javascript, but the code below still seems a little complicated for me. I have extracted this codes from a example on david-tang.net website. Although there are explanation in it, but after reading it, I am still a little confused. It there anyone out there who can help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

```
/*
 * ajax static method
 * example:
 * dQuery.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxResponse.php',
        data: 'fname=David&age=25',
        success: function (response) {}
    });
 */

dQuery.ajax = (function () {
    var xhr;
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    var IEversions = ["Microsoft.XmlHttp",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0"];

    for(var i=0, len = IEversions.length; i<len; i++) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject(IEversions[i]);
            break;
        }
        catch(e) {
        }
    }      
}

return function (param) {
    var url = param.url+'?'+param.data;    
    function checkReadiness () {
        if (xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }
        else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            param.success(xhr.responseText);
        }
        else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Ajax request failed');
        }
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = checkReadiness;
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.send('');
}
})();
```

Source: [http://david-tang.net/]

---

```
dQuery.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxResponse.php',
        data: 'fname=David&age=25',
        success: function (response) {}
    });



return function (param) {
    var url = param.url+'?'+param.data;    
    function checkReadiness () {
        if (xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }
        <b> 
            else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            param.success(xhr.responseText); 
        </b>
        }
        else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Ajax request failed');
        }
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = checkReadiness;
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.send('');
}
```

does this means that the success function is mapped to the param.success when the readyState is 4 and xhr.status is 200? but where is the line which returns param to the function? such that whenever in javascript success:function(response) {} is called, the response is the param?

---

in the testQuery.js

```
(function (window, undefined) {

var testQuery = function(obj) {
    if (!(this instanceof testQuery)) {
        return new testQuery(obj);
}


testQuery.alertMessage = (function () {
    alert("alert");
})();

}) (window);
```

in the testQuery.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="testQuery.js"></script>
<script>

function click() {

testQuery.alertMessage({});

}
```

```
<body>

<input type="button" value="click" onclick="click()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what exactly don't you understand? Also, what have you understood or figured out so far?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? You're unlikely to get someone giving you a line-by-line breakdown of what that code does...

Comment: @Vivin Paliath thanks for your reply. i am actually not too sure about how the example at the top which i suppose it is the way to use this method in the javascript flows into the method like it should be.

Comment: @James Allardice Does that means that the return function maps to the success: function(data) { } in the javascript codes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, they create a *closure*. This is a function that can contain basically everything to execute and returns something in the end. What is returned is set to `dQuery.ajax`:

```
dQuery.ajax = (function() {
    // ...
})();
```

Inside the closure they first create an engine to use when making AJAX requests. In all sane browsers, the engine is `XMLHttpRequest`. In Internet Explorer you need to try out a lot of other ways, including ActiveX Objects, which is what they do next (iterating through all ActiveX Objects that can be used for AJAX and see whether it is available).

Then, they return a function, which is going to be stored in `dQuery.ajax` (because it is the thing returned by the closure). This function first concatenates the URL and query string, so that `test.php` and `foo=bar` becomes the valid URL `test.php?foo=bar`.

After that they create a function (inside the return function - that's possible), which is fired everytime the AJAX engine state changes. The point is that it fires this event more often than you'd like to. You basically only want to do something in case the response is received and everything is correct. So they break off the function in case `readyState < 4`. When the state is `4` and the HTTP response code is `200` (which is `OK` - so successful), they call the function passed through the `param` parameter, in its turn passing the response text to that function.

Outside that function they just fire off the request.

So, if you call like:

```
dQuery.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url: "ajax.php",
             data:"id="+id ,
             success: function(data){
                 //response is in the data
            });
```

then the URL has become `ajax.php?id=123` (depending on the value of `id`), the request is fired off (with `GET` as `param.type` is nowhere used - are you missing something perhaps?), and when it's complete, the `success` function is called where `data` is the response text.

**Edit:** In a function, you can call an argument if it is a function:

```
function foo(func) {
    func(12); // Call the function and pass 12 as its first argument
}

function addone(x) {
    alert(x + 1); // When arrived here, x === 12
}

foo(addone); // This will eventually alert 13
```

**Edit2:** In response to what you posted:

```
(function (window, undefined) { // Start the closure, good

var testQuery = function(obj) { // Create a testQuery object, fine
    if (!(this instanceof testQuery)) {
        return new testQuery(obj);
}


testQuery.alertMessage = (function () { // Add a function, OK
    alert("alert");
})();

}) (window); // Oops - end of closure already.
             // Things have been defined but not exposed.
             // Just do window.testQuery = testQuery before the end of the closure,
             // so that you can actually use testQuery outside the closure.
             // Currently, testQuery is only accessible inside the closure, but
             // obviously you'd like to use it anywhere.
```

**Edit3**: You are defining a function by *calling* it. That is not really necessary. Just do (like you define `testQuery`):

```
testQuery.alertMessage = function () {
    alert("alert");
};
```

Secondly, you have no closing `}` of the `if` clause:

```
if (!(this instanceof testQuery)) {
    return new testQuery(obj);
} // <-- important!
```

It then works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/UFfSf/.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks for your clear explanation. it has helped me understand better. but i am still wondering how is the data in the success function being mapped? i have added a little more code in the question, hope that helps. thanks.

Comment: @simplified.: I hope my amendment explains it.

Comment: @pimvdb hmm, i think i got what you mean. just to clarify, does this means that when func(12) is called it sets x? means there's a function somewhere? anyway does the foo and bar has a meaning to it?

Comment: @simplified.: Yes, `func(12)` just calls `func` with `x` set to `12`, because `x` is the first argument of `func` (which is equal to `addone`) and `12` is the first argument passed. `foo`/`bar` are just names of various things used in tutorials without a real meaning.

Comment: @pimvdb i understand what you are talking about but i was trying to write a simple library to test what i learn but it doesn't work. it is just as simple as having the library method being called where the library will do an alert. can you help me with this too?

Comment: @simplified.: Do you mean a library with a function that alerts something?

Comment: @pimvdb yeah. i was trying to test to see how can i actually make a little progress in it. i have attached what i have written in the question. thanks.

Comment: @simplified.: I think I got your point, please have another look at the answer.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks. i have added the window.testQuery = testQuery. but it still doesn't seem to work. is there something wrong with the way i called it from the javascript in the html?

Comment: @simplified.: My bad, I was overlooking something. Will edit.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks! it works now the alert comes out. but again, it turns out that the alert is called when the library is loaded, but not to my clicks. I did the var testQuery = testQuery.alertMessage; in the click() function though.

Comment: @simplified.: Are you adding the button in jsFiddle? In that case it might not work because the JavaScript code there is loaded after adding the HTML which is too late. Also, `click` is a reserved function name it seems - try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UFfSf/2/.

Comment: @pimvdb hmm, it's written on a local copy though. i have also changed the click to onclick but it still doesn't work. it seems that the alertmessage function in the library is called everytime it loads. do i need to include a handler or something for my clicks on the button?

Comment: @simplified.: This is what I mean in the end: http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=91591&c=9649920.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks, it works now, seems like the problem was with the library, i accidentally added a open and close bracket after the testQuery.alertMessage = (function() { alert("alert");})(); after removing it then it works perfectly fine. thanks for your help once again!

Comment: @simplified.: Just for the sake of organisation, could you please accept the answer that helped you. Thanks.